# new update in scikit learn cross validation library

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am learning ML from machine learning course a-z on udemy. In the code template of data preprocessing it is given as

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)
```

But when I ran it it is given that there is no sklearn.cross_validation. On googling I found that instead we should use sklearn. How to this  in the latest version of sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split but even that is not a class. How to do that in the newest version

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific about which version you are using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deprecation warnings from sklearn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43302400/deprecation-warnings-from-sklearn). Also look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45009249/3374996)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please use

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

using sklearn version 0.18 and above.

Answer (score 1):

The train_test_split was moved to the model_selection from cross_validation in 0.18 of scikit-learn. Please update scikit-learn to 0.18 or to recent version.

you can update through command line by:

```
pip install --upgrade scikit-learn
```

or

```
conda update scikit-learn   (if using conda environment).
```

---